# Insert some data using post but entity model object comming null values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I tried insert db postman using some data but the model value all data comming null This is my code can you help me on this.

```
[Route("api/admission")] 
public class AdmissionController : Controller 
{ 
    private readonly PodarSiteDbContext _context;

    public AdmissionController(PodarSiteDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string test(Admission admission)
    {
        var admin = new Admission();

        _context.Admission.Add(admin);
        return admission.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your action waits for an `Admission` model but inside you're creating a new one (which has everything null) and adding it to the db, shouldn't you be using the `admission` you got from the request

Comment: How do you pass the admission parameter, via query string or over the body?

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki Yes I passed over the body

Comment: shouldn't you use the [FromBody] attribute on the method parameter in this case?

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki I used [FromBody] it's working thanks.

Comment: Would you mark my response as answer please?

Comment: Note: in this case, `[FromBody]` was required because the controller class itself was not decorated with `[ApiController]`, apparently. If you do have the `[ApiController]` attribute applied, then the default is `[FromBody]`, no longer requiring that to be applied to the parameter explictly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the parameter with the [FromBody] attribute to outline the source of its data.